# Node JS is says method isn't there when it clearly is

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Alright, so I've created a test project to show off this error. The error being that Node JS can't find my getStr function in my Another object.

This is the code:

## test.js

```
var Another = require('./another.js');
var Other = require('./other.js');

var otherStr = Other.getStr();

console.log(otherStr);
```

## other.js

```
var Another = require('./another.js');

var str = Another.getStr();
```

## another.js

```
var Other = require('./other.js');

var str = "other String";

exports.getStr = function(){
    return str;
}
```

And this is my output:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\JS DEV\NODE DEV\server\test>node test.js

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\JS DEV\NODE DEV\server\test\other.js:3
var str = Another.getStr();
                  ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getStr'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\JS DEV\NODE DEV\server\test\ot
her.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\JS DEV\NODE DEV\server\test\an
other.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\JS DEV\NODE DEV\server\test>
```

So how do I get Node JS to see Another's getStr function in Other?

Comment: It should work fine. Try `console.log(Another);`

Comment: Where would I put that?

Comment: After `var Another = require('./another.js');`

Comment: the output is just {} for the log output, and then the error again.

Comment: Doesn't `another.js` has anything else, at all?

Comment: I don't understand that question :( Sorry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51919/discussion-between-thefourtheye-and-cyanprime)

Comment: The sequence here is: `test.js`->`another.js`->`other.js` via `another.js`->calls `another.getStr` in `other.js`->register `another.getStr` in `another.js`->calls `other.getStr` in `test.js`. So the problem is when you fetch `another.getStr` in `other.js` the first time, it's not exported yet.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I at least know what the problem is. Any idea how to fix it? I'm on v0.10.26 by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're dealing with here is a circular dependency. Node.js will *let* you load modules in a circular way but you need to design your code to account for it. **Generally speaking, a circular dependency is a sign that the design is suffering from some flaw.** In the code you've shown in the question, `another` requires `other` but does nothing with it. So the simplest fix would be to change `another` so that it does not require `other`.

If you have to keep the circular dependency for some reason or you want to experiment with circular dependencies for learning purposes, then this would be another possible fix:

```
var str = "other String";

exports.getStr = function(){
    return str;
}

var Other = require('./other');

// Actually do something with Other down here.
```

By the time `other` is required `another` will at least have `getStr` available. So this takes care of the immediate issue. Note however that your `other` module does not export anything so your `test.js` file will still fail at `var otherStr = Other.getStr();` Probably you forgot to add this:

```
exports.getStr = function(){
    return str;
}
```

(Note: I've modified the `require` call so that it requires `other` without the `.js` suffix. Generally, you don't want to put suffixes in your `require` calls. You want to put a module name which Node can resolve to a file, a package, or something else.)